# cakephp login across whole site

Tags: php, session, cakephp, authentication, oauth

I'm logging in with the HybridAuth plug-in at the address = /cake/hybridauth/auth/google, then I use these details to look up the user on the database and log them in to the default CakePHP Auth like so:

```
   $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($hybridauth_config);
   $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider);
   $userprofile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
    //look up user + register if not found

        $this->loadModel('User');

        $isUser = $this->User->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'User.provider' => strtolower($provider),
                        'User.identifier' => $userprofile->identifier
                    ),
                    'callbacks' => true
                ));

        if(!$isUser){
            //register the user
        } else {
            //update user with new credentials
            $this->Auth->login($isUser["User"]);

            //this doesn't work across the whole site, 
            //only this controller's "action" page
        }
```

This all works fine, until I go back to my homepage at /cake/, where there seems to be no recognition of me having logged in - although on the controller's action page (cake/hybridauth/auth/google) I have the user logged into the Auth component and the above code seemed to work...

Any ideas what I'm missing please?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know Cake well, but maybe a Cookie is being set that applies to the `/hybridauth/auth/google` path only? (when no explicit path is specified, the current path is used)

Comment: I thought it could have been that but no cookies are being set... Its odd because one minute the data is in the session, then on the homepage its not...

Comment: Use `debug($this->Session->read());` to determine what session data is present on your homepage. If it isn't there then it's being deleted somewhere, if it is then there may just be an issue with your call. Please also check that your session ID stays consistent, if it's changing it may remove your access to the data.

Comment: Thanks @Alex it seems this is the issue but how do I prevent this from happening? I've tried setting the security to low, but on each reload of my controllers page it generates a new session...